# How do I dual boot Windows and Archlinux when they are physically installed in different harddrive?

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

I installed Arch Linux and Windows in separate harddrive (not partition, but real spinning disk drive). Each OS has their own boot because I was hoping to move Arch Linux directly to another machine later on. Now I have two booloaders installed in separate drives. I do not want to modify /boot in Arch Linux because that OS will be taken out in the future.

Ideally, I want to bootup Windows's bootloader and have a choice between two bootloaders (grub for linux and windows boot manager for windows), how do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Windows application that can configure Windows boot manager to add a Linux installation: [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)
This being said, it's still easier to boot to grub and when you take out Linux, you just change the BIOS setting to boot back to the Windows drive.

Comment: In the second case (I boot to grub in linux), how do I add Windows bootloader to grub? The windows is installed in a different harddrive.

Comment: `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` should find Windows automatically.

Comment: I just ran the command, it did not find windows per the log... What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have an UEFI computer? If yes, you shouldn't use grub, check the Archlinux wiki.